# C++ How do i run makefile output

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans, makefile, cppunit

C++ How do i run makefile output

Below is my MakeFile, I want to ask how do i run my unitTest.cpp, as because when i MakeFile with NetBean, using the MakeFile below, main.exe is actually the main.cpp output

BUT I want to run the output of unitTest.cpp

How do i run unitTest.cpp

```
# ExampleTests Project

SRCS = main.cpp currencyConverter.cpp unitTest.cpp

HDRS = currencyConverter.h unitTest.h

PROJ = main



# Remaining lines shouldn't need changing

# Here's what they do:

#   - rebuild if any header file or this Makefile changes

#   - include CppUnit as dynamic library

#   - search /opt/local for MacPorts

#   - generate .exe files for Windows

#   - add -enable-auto-import flag for Cygwin only



CC = g++

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

APP = $(PROJ).exe

CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall -I/opt/local/include

ifeq (,$(findstring CYGWIN,$(shell uname)))

  LDFLAGS = -L/opt/local/lib

else

  LDFLAGS = -L/opt/local/lib -enable-auto-import

endif

LIBS = -lcppunit -ldl



all: $(APP)



$(APP): $(OBJS)

    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(APP) $(LIBS)



%.o: %.cpp $(HDRS)

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@



clean:

    rm -f *.o $(APP)
```

Below is my unitTest.cpp

```
#include "unitTest.h"
#include "currencyConverter.h"

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(unitTest);


unitTest::unitTest() {
}

unitTest::~unitTest() {
}

void unitTest::setUp() {
}

void unitTest::tearDown() {
}

void stringToUpper(string&);

void unitTest::testStringLowerToUpper()
{
string str = "ILOVECPLUSPLUS";
string str2 = "IloveCplusplus";

cout << "\nChecking if string 1 '" << str << "' equals string 2 '" << str2 << "'";
CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(str,str2);

//this part i will use my stringToUpperFunction to test.
currencyConverter c;

c.stringToUpper(str2);

cout << "\nChecking if string 1 '" << str << "' equals string 2 '" << str2 << "'";
CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(str,str2);

}
```

Comment: Actually, the executable `main.exe` is _all_ the source files linked together, including the code in `unitTest.cpp`.

Comment: But how do i run unitTest.cpp  and see its output if all linked together.

Comment: You need to write a _rule_ for building unitTest in your makefile. Does `unitTest.cpp` have a `main()`?

Comment: added my unitTest codes.

Comment: As `unitTest.cpp` is not a standalone program (it has no `main` function of its own), you have to call the functions from somewhere. As it seems that NetBeans can have several projects inside a single workspace, I would suggest you create a completely new project for the unit testing, using the files needed from the original project when needed. This new project should contain a file having a `main` function which calls the tests.

Comment: It is helpful to understand what `make` does. It looks to see which of your target's dependencies are newer than the target and runs the associated shell commands. That's all. Usually those build a program. If you want to run your tests you need to *build and invoke a program which runs the tests*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another target (e.g. `testrunner.exe`) dependent on the .cpp files you want to test + your testsuite .cpp files + another .cpp file that consitutes the main() for your testrunner application to your make file. Having this you can add another target test, dependent on `testrunner.exe` that just calls the testrunner.exe executable.

Comment: Sry, didn't see that you're generating the makfile using NetBean (however?). I think then the solution using an extra project for your tests seems to be more appropriate.

Comment: How should my new project makefile like ?

Comment: It should look exactly the same as the one you demonstrate in your question, supposed `main.cpp` calls cppunit's testrunner + that additional target to call your tests ($APP in this case). You won't need to link (depend on) `unitTest.cpp` in your main project.